# Arrays and objects and javascript map

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have a problem. I have this array that I want to convert to an object with dynamic data.

this is the function

```js
const prodSheet2 = prodSheet.map(da => 
                   ({ Artikelnummer: da[0], 
                        Benämning: da[1],
                        AnnanBemäning: da[2],
                        Kortnman: da[3],
                        Artikelgrupp: da[4]}))
```

and this expels data as:

```
    0 : {Artikelnummer: 100010, Benämning: aaa, AnnaBenämning: aaa, Kortnamn: a, Artikelgrupp:101}
    1 : {Artikelnummer: 100011, Benämning: aaa, AnnaBenämning: aaa, Kortnamn: b, Artikelgrupp:101}
```

but I wanted it to be like:

```
    100010 : {Artikelnummer: 100010, Benämning: aaa, AnnaBenämning: aaa, Kortnamn: a, Artikelgrupp:101}
    100011 : {Artikelnummer: 100011, Benämning: aaa, AnnaBenämning: aaa, Kortnamn: b, Artikelgrupp:101}
```

I have been trying different ways but cannot figure out. I am writing this in ReactJs

Comment: Please click `[<>]` snippet editor and create a [mcve] noting ***INPUT*** and expected output. Where does the 10010 come from?

Comment: do you want a single object with `Artikelnummer` as keys, or more objects?

Answer (score 1):

```
 const prodSheet2 = prodSheet.map(da => 
               ([da[0]]:{ Artikelnummer: da[0], 
                    Benämning: da[1],
                    AnnanBemäning: da[2],
                    Kortnman: da[3],
                    Artikelgrupp: da[4]}))
```

try this or check the js computed value

Comment: This is wrong - you need to use return when using a map, otherwise you will get undefined.

Comment: @Harmenx No you don't. The return is implicit with an arrow function. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Answer (score 1):

You could reduce the array and get a single object with `Artikelnummer` as key for the item informations.

```
const prodSheet2 = prodSheet.reduce((o, da) =>({
    ...o,
    [da[0]]: {
        Artikelnummer: da[0],
        'Benämning': da[1],
        'AnnanBemäning': da[2],
        Kortnman: da[3],
        Artikelgrupp: da[4]
   }
}), {});
```

Comment: Artikelnummer is `undefined`, want to use da[0] instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ES6 spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) & [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) like below

```js
var prodSheet = 
[
  [100010, "aaa", "aaa", "a", 101],
  [100011, "aaa", "aaa", "b", 101]
];
var result2 = Object.assign({}, ...prodSheet.map(da => ({[da[0]]: { Artikelnummer: da[0], 
                    Benämning: da[1],
                    AnnanBemäning: da[2],
                    Kortnman: da[3],
                    Artikelgrupp: da[4]}})));

                    
console.log(result2);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? Let me know if you need any help @Oblicion A

Answer (score 0):

```
    const prodSheet2 = prodSheet.map(da => {
        var key = da[0]
        var obj = {}
        obj[key] = {
            da : { 
                Artikelnummer: da[0], 
                Benämning: da[1],
                AnnanBemäning: da[2],
                Kortnman: da[3],
                Artikelgrupp: da[4]
            }
        }
        return obj
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work.

```
 const prodSheet2 = prodSheet.reduce((acc, next) => {
    return { 
        ...acc,
        [next[0]]: {
            Artikelnummer: next[0],
            Benämning: next[1],
            AnnanBemäning: next[2],
            Kortnman: next[3],
            Artikelgrupp: next[4]
        }
    };
 }, {});
```